# Modal does not close

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

When pressing the "Confirm" button, it executes the function and the action, but the event of closing the modal does not execute it.

This is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("document").ready(function() {
    var actsel = $("#act_selected").val();
    $("#habilitaract_mensaje").html("¿You want to end the activity No. <strong>" + actsel + "</strong>?");
    
    $("#btn_actconfirmar").click(function() {
      if (habHabitacion()) {
        $('#modal_habilitaract').modal('hide');
      }
     });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Enable Activity</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <h5><span id="habilitaract_mensaje"></span></h5>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_actconfirmar">
              <span class="texto-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Confirm</span>
            </button>

    </div>
```

Comment: What does the `habHabitacion` function do? Only it seems to prevent the hiding of the modal..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from your import of bootstrapp or the definition of the div of the modal
Look at mine:it works correctly

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
  $("document").ready(function() {
    var actsel = $("#act_selected").val();  
  $("#habilitaract_mensaje").html("¿You want to end the activity No. <strong>" + actsel + "</strong>?");    
  $("#btn_actconfirmar").click(function() {
    alert("welcome");
   });
 });
</script>

<div align="right"> 
  <button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>  
 </div> 
<div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade">  
 <div class="modal-dialog">  
<div class="modal-content">  
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;
</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Enable Activity</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <h5><span id="habilitaract_mensaje"></span></h5>
    <br>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_actconfirmar">
          <span class="texto-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Confirm</span>
        </button>

      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If habHabitacion function returns boolean true then modal window should be close. Please check what habHabitacion return.